# DirectShow: ieee1394id <- does that also describe USB devices?

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

I am trying to understand a DirectShow library implementation.

What is a IEEE1394-id in DirectShow terminology?

IEEE1394 is firewire.

Does it usually also describe ids for
USB devices?

it gets retrieved by IAMExtDevice::get_ExternalDeviceID()

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.  IEEE1394 is the standard for highspeed communications with peripheral devices defined as a replacement for SCSI, among other things.  It's techincally called IEEE1394, whereas Firewire is merely a brand (Apple) and is also called i.LINK (Sony).

USB is a separate standard defined about a year later, although it's gone through a couple of revisions - USB 2.0 and USB3.0, but was defined by an industry group (USB-IF - USB Implementors Forum), members of which included Intel, IBM and Microsoft.

Some handy links for more information:

[USB on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)

[IEEE1394 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewire)

Comment: I know that. I want to know, If in the DirectShow world, it means the same for all capture devices, USB as well as FireWire/I.Link